# Send mail automatically near MySQL datetime

Tags: mysql, sql, email, datetime

In my MySQL database I have a table containing a datetime column. I'd like to send emails whenever current time is 30 minutes before one of the datetime values.
E.g. datetime value is '20140623180000' the server should send a mail at 17:30 on 23rd June 2014. The values in the datetime column aren't regular. Anyone knows how to do this in an easy way? (Linux running on server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you will need a cron to run every minute that looks for records where datetime < currenttime

Then loop through the results and send the necessary email.

i.e.

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
$db = new PDO($dsn);
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE datetime > ?");
$stmt->execute(array(date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("-30 minutes")));
$r = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($r as $res){
  mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
?>
```

## NOT TESTED

Comment: I already thought I'd have to use cron for that. Got a slightly different implementation working. Thanks!