# Start php function at the time of a mysql datetime object

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, cron

I have this situation on my Linux server:

My MySQL database table includes a column 'datetime' holding a datetime object.
I want to read the datetime values of the table rows using PHP, and if one of the values equals the current time, a second PHP function (or script) should start working. The problem is, that this PHP code will run for a longer time (probably 2 hours), which means the next datetime entry might match the current time before the second script/code execution is finished.

The datetime entries in the database do not represent regular intervals, and it's possible that two or more entries contain the same datetime representation. In this case, for each of the entries the second script should be executed.

I wouldn't mind if the second code starts a minute after the datetime time is reached, so it's not necessary to hit the *exact* time stored in the mysql entries. Important is only to start the code **shortly** after this time **once** for **each** entry.

I asked about a similar case some time ago ([Send mail automatically near MySQL datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24343888/send-mail-automatically-near-mysql-datetime)), but this didn't require a second longer running script.

I'm not sure if a **cronjob** running every minute or something like that will do it, since I need to start it only once per entry. I'm not sure if you understand my situation and if it's possible to realize with PHP

Any help and basic ideas appreciated.

Comment: 2 hour for a php script execution o.O what are you doing in there. php servers have `max-execution-time` for scripts, which is mostly within seconds.

Comment: What exactly does this script? Why it has to be exact? Because you can run a cronjob each minute and iterate a while for a minute and check the database. This way you cover every single second.

Comment: @Bsienn: well, it contains a loop which will wait ~5 min after every iteration

Comment: @machineaddict Are you sure I don't hit some database entries twice this way?

Comment: You can add a column on that table with a status. When you start proccesing it, it changes. The next cronjob, even if it starts before the first one finishes, it will not get the same row from database.

Comment: @machineaddict: I implemented it the way you suggested in your comments, and it seems to work even without the extra status column. Since I don't need it to be that exact, it's sufficient for me to generate a timestamp at the beginning of each cronjob. When looping over the sql query results, I always compare with the timestamp generated. Doing it like this, every table row is processed in the correct cronjob and not hit twice.